# How to create new text file in one login session?

Tags: jsp, logging

I would like to create new file and log some new information for a new login, but i'm getting the problem which it write in the same log file continuously. How do I create a new file once I log in? I have jsp code in my logincheck.jsp file.

```
    <%
        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
        //String ADDRESS = request.getRemoteAddr();
        InetAddress thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        String strPath = "C:\\Users\\learningAppLogFile\\mylog.txt";
        File strFile = new File(strPath);

        boolean fileCreated = strFile.createNewFile();

        try{
    if(!strFile.exists()){
        strFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(strFile, true);

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.write("  [" + date + "]  :  [" + username + "]  :  [" + thisIp + "]  ");
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    bufferedWriter.close();

} catch(IOException e) {
}%>
```

Comment: Do you want to create new file or override the existing data or want to append it in the end?

Comment: @Braj no. i want to create a file with different name. For example, i have a log.txt now where it generated by system automatically, but after I run again the system, i want it create new file named log2.txt or something like log.txt.2

Comment: use a counter in below sample code and increment it in `sessionCreated()` method and create a new log file on sign-in event.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I create a new file once I log in? I want to create a file with different name.
>
> For example, i have a log.txt now where it generated by system automatically, but after I run again the system, i want it create new file named log2.txt or something like log.txt.2

Here’s a simple [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) example to keep monitor your session’s create and remove behavior, then consider this listener.

Sample code:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
 
public class SessionCounterListener implements HttpSessionListener {
 
  private int counter=0;

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("sessionCreated");
    
    counter++;
    // create a new file appending counter value in the file name

    // Here log the sign-in events
  }
 
  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("sessionDestroyed");
     // Here do whatever you want to do on sign out event
  } 
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.x.y.z.SessionCounterListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

---

### How it work?

- If a new session is created , e.g `request.getSession();` , the listener’s `sessionCreated()` will be executed.
- If a session is destroyed, e.g session’s timeout or `session.invalidate()`, the listener’s `sessionDestroyed()` will be executed.

Sample code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(); //sessionCreated() is executed
...
session.invalidate();  //sessionDestroyed() is executed
```

For more info visit [mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/) from where this example is referred.

---

#### Some points

- Always try to avoid Scriplet instead use JSTL and EL.
- Move the code in above listener class from JSP.